# Magento 2.0 Backend model

Tags: magento2, model, system.xml

Hey I am a noob to Magento 2.I am trying to work on a module where I am passing a class as backendModel for a config field in `system.xml`, but I am getting an error as :

> Critical:Invalid Config field backend model:"Classpath"

Can someone tell me how to use backend_model class in Magento 2.0 and what class it should extend in order to avoid above error?

Answer (score 0):

Backend Model Name should full class name. Please verify that you have class `Classpath`.

Comment: Yes I have passed correct path and classname

Comment: A solution telling me to add Magento\Core\Model\Config\Data
but this module nomore exist in magento2..what can be alternate for it?

Comment: Can you update you question if  you new have other problem